# Android PagerAdapter not calling instantiateItem

Tags: android, adapter

I'm trying to implement ViewPager with PagerAdapter in my app. I'm mainly working off [this example](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/537).

My `PagerAdapter` is called DataPagerAdapter and uses the following constructor and `instantiateItem`, where I inflate a view from `data_list_view.xml`:

```
public class DataPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter
    implements TitleProvider {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    
    private static String[] titles = new String[]
    {
        "Page 1",
        "Page 2",
        "Page 3"
    };
    private final Context context;
 
    public DataPagerAdapter( Context context )
    {
        this.context = context;
    }
 
    @Override
    public String getTitle( int position )
    {
        return titles[ position ];
    }
 
    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return titles.length;
    }
 
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem( View pager, int position )
    {
        ListView v = (ListView) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.data_list_view, null);
        ((ViewPager)pager).addView( v, 0 );
        return v;
    }
 
    @Override
    public void destroyItem( View pager, int position, Object view )
    {
        ((ViewPager)pager).removeView( (ListView)view );
    }
 
    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject( View view, Object object )
    {
        return view.equals( object );
    }
 
    @Override
    public void finishUpdate( View view ) {}
 
    @Override
    public void restoreState( Parcelable p, ClassLoader c ) {}
 
    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }
 
    @Override
    public void startUpdate( View view ) {}
}
```

And in my activity I get my adapter:

```
DataPagerAdapter adapter = new DataPagerAdapter( this );
```

And then later I want to refer to my dataListView in code:

```
dataListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewData);
```

Problem is, the `dataListView` is returned as null by the `findViewById` call since the `instantiateItem` is never processed.

When is `instantiateItem` called and is this done automatically (as the example seems to suggest) or do I have to force it somehow?

Comment: You need to make sure you are filling out all of the methods in the PagerAdapter, such as getCount(), isViewFromObject(), etc.  Could you add a bit more code to your question?

Comment: I added the full code of the DataPagerAdapter. I basically tweaked the code used in the example from the link I provided.

Answer (score 24):

Note, that your adapter uses deprecated methods:

```
public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position)
public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object)
```

The API says to use these instead:

```
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object)
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case the problem was I set `ViewPager` visibility to `GONE` by mistake  and it was not getting called . Just make viewPager visibility to visible in layout.